# Got errors when publish

Tags: vb.net

I am facing problem to publish. I want publish my VB project but i have got these problems. What should I do?

first error:

> An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe. SignTool Error: The signer's certificate is not valid for signing. SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign:bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe

Second error:

> Cannot publish because a project failed to build.

Third error:

> Item 'Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0'could not be located in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Are you targeting .NET 2.0?

Comment: @AustrianDairyman, I am using Version 2010. No. I am targeting to .NET 4.0

Comment: Did you apply a certificate to it or at least create a temporary one? If you're not sure, look at your project properties on the "Signing" tab.